# Cannot locate CTest configuration

Tags: cmake, ctest

I am trying to perform a coverage analysis of a project in which I use CMake+CTest. I have created a simple TestingScript.cmake that looks like:

```
set(CTEST_SOURCE_DIRECTORY .)
set(CTEST_BINARY_DIRECTORY build_coverage)

ctest_start(TestCoverage)

ctest_coverage(BUILD ${CTEST_BINARY_DIR})
```

and am trying to run it with:

```
doriad@david-desktop:~/build/Examples/Coverage$ ctest -S ~/src/Examples/Coverage/TestingScript.cmake 
Cannot locate CTest configuration: in BuildDirectory: /home/doriad/build/Examples/Coverage/build_coverage/CTestConfig.cmake
Cannot locate CTest configuration: in SourceDirectory: /home/doriad/build/Examples/Coverage/CTestConfig.cmake
 Cannot find any coverage files. Ignoring Coverage request.
```

What do I need to do to produce this CTestConfig.cmake file that it is looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `CTestConfig.cmake` is usually generated by CDash. While logged in to CDash, select **Settings > Project > Miscellaneous > Download CTestConfig**. The file holds the configuration to submit the results to a dashboard server.

> The default settings of the module are to submit the dashboard to Kitware's Public Dashboard, where you can register your project for free.
>
> In order to submit to some other server, `CTestConfig.cmake` in the top level directory of your source, and set your own dashboard preferences. If you are using a CDash server, you can download a preconfigured file from the respective project page on that server (*Settings* / *Project*, tab *Miscellaneous*).
>
> *Source: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/ctest/Testing-With-CTest*

Another problem is that you have no coverage files to submit since you skipped the **build** and **test** steps in your testing script.